# how to solve the error 1001 DNS resolution error

Tags: iis-10

When I access localhost on IIS using the default website, the page that appears is not the default iis page, but this 1001 error page. It worked fine before, I just ran into this problem after setting the hostname and binding HTTPS in iis website, anybody know why that is? Even if I remove my Settings, it's still the same problem.

[error 1001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XSWn.png)

Comment: Looks like your DNS server is set to cloudfare , validate your DNS server ```ipconfig /displaydns``` (try replacing Primary DNS to 8.8.8.8 - Google) , after making changes flush DNS cache and try accessing again ```ipconfig /flushdns```. Also localhost don't redirect to aspnettest.com by default - validate website bindings and your host file any entry

Comment: Run a report https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html and the cause should be clear.

Comment: I think you may bind localhost to another IP instead of 127.0.0.1 in the host file, so it jumps to cloudflare network.